# MYSQL select a piece of a string and order by that piece

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a field with this kind of info "web-1/1.,web-2/2.,web-3/3.,web-4/4.,web-5/5.".  Other registers could have different values like "web-1/4.,web-2/5.,web-3/1.,web-4/2.,web-5/3."

I want to select and order by lets say web-2/? would be web-2/1, web-2/2, web-2/3 and so on all fields that contain web-2 and order by the last number

I want to create a featured properties script different websites and specify feature number.  Different properties, different websites different order

Comment: This would be much simpler if the data was normalized (not stored as comma/etc delimited lists).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would suggest that you look at the [MySQL String Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) and more specifically the [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function. The reason I suggest this one over `SUBSTRING` is because the number before or after the slash might be more than a single number which would make the length of the first and/or second parts vary.

**Example:**

```
SELECT   `info`,
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(`info`, '/', 1) AS `first_part`,
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(`info`, '/', -1) AS `second_part`
FROM     `table`
ORDER BY `first_part` ASC,
         `second_part` ASC;
```

**Result:**

[image: Result]

**Additional Example**

In this example, I'm using [`CAST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) to convert the second part into an unsigned integer just in case it contains additional characters such as symbols or letters. In other words, the second part of "web-4/15." would be "15" and the second part of "web-4/15****" would also be "15".

```
SELECT   `info`,
          SUBSTRING_INDEX(`info`, '/', 1) AS `first_part`,
          CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`info`, '/', -1) AS UNSIGNED) `second_part`
FROM     `table`
ORDER BY `first_part` ASC,
         `second_part` ASC;
```

Comment: Ahh, I see your point. But wouldn't this solution view the second_part as a string and only work for values 0-9?

Comment: @Martin - No. Actually, I used that code to split IP addresses and I just realized that I over-complicated it by using the two `SUBSTRING_INDEX` together. I've updated my answer but with that said the -1 in the `SUBSTRING_INDEX` find the last match (so what's after the slash in this case).

Comment: example i have this in the field "web-1/2.,web-2/3,web-3/4.,web-4/5.,web-5/1." and i want to order and select rows that contains "web-3/" and order by the value after the slash "/4"

Comment: @charlymz - Are you suggesting that there may be a period (.) after the last number? Do you want to include the slash when sorting? And is "/4" supposed to be the last number or only for ones that end in "/4"? I'm a little unclear as to what you mean.

Comment: i like your method but i did some adjustments  
SELECT   `websites`,
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`websites`, 'web-5/', -1), ',', 1) AS `second_part` 
FROM     `properties_featured`
WHERE   websites LIKE '%web-5/%'
ORDER BY length(second_part) ASC, second_part ASC;

it gives me:
websites                                            second_part
web-1/2.,web-2/3.,web-3/45.,web-4/5.,web-5/1           1
web-1/4.,web-2/5.,web-3/1.,web-4/2.,web-5/3            3
web-1/5.,web-2/1.,web-3/2.,web-4/3.,web-5/4            4
web-1/1.,web-2/2.,web-4/4.,web-5/5                     5

Answer (score 0):

If the strings will always match the pattern you described, we can assume that the first value you want to sort on is index position 5 in the string (5 characters from the left).  The second character is index 7.  With that in mind, you can do the following, assuming that the string 'web-2/1' is in a field named field:

```
SELECT
  `field`
FROM
  `table`
ORDER BY
  substr(`field`, 5, 1) ASC,
  substr(`field`, 7, 1) ASC;
```

The substr() functions take the field as the first option, the index we mentioned above, and an option third parameter which is the count for how many characters to include starting from the second option.

You can tweak this as necessary if the string is slightly off, the main thing being the second option in the subtr() function.

Comment: As I explained in my answer, using `SUBSTR` (which is the sane as `SUBSTRING`) isn't necessarily the best option in this case. In the question, they length of the first and second parts are the same but that may not always be the case. `SUBSTRING_INDEX` might be a better option.

Answer (score 0):

Just add: `...ORDER BY SUBSTRING(username, 2) ASC`

Answer (score -1):

I would do this

```
SELECT info
FROM table
WHERE info LIKE 'web-2%'
ORDER BY info ASC
```

Comment: If there's a lot of entries, I would not recommend running a like comparison.  It may seem effective with smaller data sets, but will choke when you have many entries.  Doesn't scale well.

Comment: In addition to @Scott's comment, the question is about ordering, not searching. The `LIKE` cannot be used to order the results.

Comment: yes and the string could be web-2/5.,web-6/4., web-5/1 and i want to order by web-6/? example

Comment: What? So a single field has a collection of comma separated values? Your problem isn't the query it's the structure. Do you have create privileges? Break those values up