# How to use substring in order by

Tags: mysql

I have the following query to select the domain names that have three levels separated by two dots:

```
select domainname from db.table
where criteria like ('*.com')
AND domainname like ('%.%.%');
```

Now, I need to order the results by the .%.% part of the domain name and not %.%.%. How can I add this to my query ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MYSQL select a piece of a string and order by that piece](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475936/mysql-select-a-piece-of-a-string-and-order-by-that-piece)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function:

```
select domainname from db.table
where criteria like ('*.com')
AND domainname like ('%.%.%')
ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(domainname, '.', -2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the function [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

```
ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(domainname, '.', -2)
```