# order mysql database by column from one give character

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql phpbb database, one of its tables, has a title column, which content is like "[data] moredata (info)"

I want to order that table in alphabetic order, but using only the "moredata" string of the title, obviating de [data] and (info)

for example:

```
[article] Advise for dummies (pdf)  
[Review] Star wars (selfWrote) 
[film] The Avengers (trailer)
```

and get the mysql table ordered like this:

```
[article] Advise for dummies (pdf)   
[film] The Avengers (trailer) 
[Review] Star wars (selfWrote)
```

using on every row, "Advise for dummies" , "The Avengers" , "Star wars" as the elment to get the alphabetic order.

Could anyone help me with that? if its not possible, Can I do it with PHP?

Comment: Is there only one `]` ever in the title? I'd take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11932363/how-to-use-substring-in-order-by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY SUBSTR(title, POSITION("]" IN title) + 1, ((POSITION("(" IN title)) - POSITION("]" IN title) - 1)) ASC`