# I need to order by a string, but string that considered is between two "/" or between two "-" how to do that

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

The current data in the table is as below

```
XBX/124/18
XX/10/18
XMX/12/18
XX/8/18
XX/123/18
XXX/88/18
XX/68/18
XX/145/18
YYY/5/18
```

the data I need should be in this format

```
XBX/5/18
XX/8/18
XMX/10/18
XX/12/18
XX/68/18
XXX/88/18
XX/123/18
XX/124/18
YYY/145/18
```

How can I do that??

Comment: How do ypu get your data? Please provide an example how you get it and what the result is. When mysql show your table structure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use substring in order by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11932363/how-to-use-substring-in-order-by)

Answer (score 1):

I Hope it will help you 
I assume that col2 is your string data is like "XBX/5/18"

```
SELECT 
      col1, 
      col2,  
      col3 
FROM 
     table1 
ORDER BY 
     SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col2, "/", 2),"/",-1);
```

This line will help you to get middle number.

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX("XBX/5/18", "/", 2),"/",-1);
```

Comment: its work but it return a string not integer ... some extra code added "   CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fieldname, '/', 2), '/', -1),UNSIGNED INTEGER) "

Answer (score 1):

for order by as above

ORDER BY CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fieldname, '/', 2), '/', -1),UNSIGNED INTEGER)

it will return middle values as an integer then we can order it

Answer (score 0):

A query solution is a good approach and probably the preferred method if you can figure out how to do it.  However, without more info to go by, here is a PHP solution that will give you the results you want.

This solution accounts for either "/" or "-" and will preserve the "/" or "-" in the sorted array.  It's ugly but it works.

```
$data = array(
  'XBX/124/18',
  'XX/10/18',
  'XMX/12/18',
  'XX/8/18',
  'XX-123-18',
  'XXX/88/18',
  'XX-68-18',
  'XX-145-18',
  'YYY/5/18'
);


for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++){

  if(preg_match('/\//', $data[$i])){

    $data[$i] = preg_replace('/\//', ' ', $data[$i]);
    $parsed[$i] = explode(' ', $data[$i]);
    $parsed[$i][3] = '/';

  }elseif(preg_match('/-/', $data[$i])){

    $data[$i] = preg_replace('/-/', ' ', $data[$i]);
    $parsed[$i] = explode(' ', $data[$i]);
    $parsed[$i][3] = '-';

    }

}

$temp = $parsed;

usort($parsed, function($a, $b){  //Will sort by middle and right values.

  if([$a[1], $a[2]] > [$b[1], $b[2]]){

    return 1;

  }elseif([$a[1], $a[2]] < [$b[1], $b[2]]){

    return -1;

    }else{

      return 0;

    }

});

for($i = 0; $i < count($parsed); $i++){ 

  $sorted[] = $temp[$i][0] . $parsed[$i][3] . $parsed[$i][1] . $parsed[$i][3] . $parsed[$i][2];

}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($sorted);
echo '</pre>';
```

This will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => XBX/5/18
    [1] => XX/8/18
    [2] => XMX/10/18
    [3] => XX/12/18
    [4] => XX-68-18
    [5] => XXX/88/18
    [6] => XX-123-18
    [7] => XX/124/18
    [8] => YYY-145-18
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get the data from the table as an array and do the following steps to order them using PHP.

```
<?php
    $arr = ['XBX/124/18', 'XX/10/18', 'XMX/12/18', 'XX/8/18', 'XX/123/18', 'XXX/88/18', 'XX/68/18', 'XX/145/18', 'YYY/5/18'];
    foreach ($arr as $str){
        $matches = substr($str, strpos($str, "/") + 1).'<br>';
        $variable[] = substr($matches, 0, strpos($matches, "/"));    
    }
    natsort($variable);
    $variable_keys = array_keys($variable);
    $ordered_array = array_replace(array_flip($variable_keys), $arr);
    $ordered_array = array_values($ordered_array);
    print_r($ordered_array);
?>
```