# MySQL: manipulate dates and strings in selection query

Tags: php, mysql, string, date, datetime

I have two columns in a MySQL table: EventStart and Distance.  EventStart is a DateTime which represents when an event begins, but Distance is a string which combines the number of miles to the event with the time to get there, such as "126.2 mi / 2 hours 35 mins".

I'd like to print the contents of the table according to when I need to LEAVE for the event, meaning I'd subtract the right half of the Distance value (everything after the "/" mark) from the EventStart.  I would like to order the results by departure times, so when I iterate the results I simply print them.

In PHP this is fairly easy:

```
$distance = substr($row['Distance'], strrpos( $row['Distance'],'/')+1);
$result = date('j M - g:i a', strtotime($row['EventStart']." -".$distance));
```

But if I have one event that starts at 10 and is 1 hour away, and one event that starts at 11 and is 3 hours away, having the MySQL `ORDER BY EventStart` the events will display with the 9 departure time listed BEFORE the 8 time, which is clearly incorrect.

Since there could be 100s of entries, I'd like to avoid making a 2D PHP array and sorting on that, so I'm looking to do it in the MySQL query directly.  I think this makes it a two part question:

1. How do I select ONLY everything after the "/" mark for the distance calculation?
2. How can I subtract that value from the EventStart so that I can order on the distance calculated?

A final note: I know storing the distance this way is a mistake; I'm picking up the project from someone else.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: [This older question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475936/mysql-select-a-piece-of-a-string-and-order-by-that-piece) contains help with your first question, although I'm afraid I have no clue about the latter part. Good luck!

Comment: Even if you are taking it over from another person, is it possible to alter the table such that you separate the 'Distance' column into 'Distance' and 'TravelTime' perhaps? And you should ideally convert the time into a common unit, say, minutes :)

Comment: I think I'm going to advise the client to pull the data apart.  Meanwhile I did a client-side sort using Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that was a little bit of fun.  I hope that you find who ever created this schema in the first place and show them the LOVE they deserve.

Something like this should work.  I've split it into subQueries to make each step a little more readable, I think.

```
SELECT miles, hours + minutes FROM (
SELECT
  cast(left(Distance, first_space) AS DECIMAL(5,2)) AS miles,
  cast(substr(Distance, distance_split_loc+1, hour_loc-distance_split_loc-1) AS unsigned) * 60 AS hours,
  cast(IF (hour_loc = 0,
    substr(Distance, distance_split_loc+1, min_loc-distance_split_loc-1),
    substr(Distance, space_after_hour, min_loc-space_after_hour)) AS unsigned) AS minutes
FROM
(SELECT
   Distance,
   locate(' ', Distance) first_space,
   locate('/', Distance) distance_split_loc,
   locate('hour', Distance) AS hour_loc,
   locate('min', Distance) AS min_loc,
   locate(' ',Distance,locate('hour', Distance)) AS space_after_hour
 FROM distance) AS temp_table) AS timecalc
ORDER BY miles;
```

[Link to SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb2942/21)

Comment: Thanks, this best answers the question I asked!  I think I'm going to make a case to fix the database instead, but your answer certainly provides the solution I asked for.  Thank you for the detailed (and complicated!) answer!

Answer (score 0):

You have to do string manipulation to get the hours and minutes out.  The following gets the number of hours out *assuming* that both "hours" and "minutes" are present:

```
select (substring(val, instr(val, '/')+2)+0) +  as hours,
       (substring(val, instr(val, 'mins')-3)+0) / 60
from (select '126.2 mi / 2 hours 5 mins' as val) t
```

Comment: Thanks, but there's no promise there will be hours.  It could be "1 mi / 5 mins"