# MySQL ORDER BY ignoring numerics

Tags: mysql

If I have 4 address lines as follows:

```
1 West Road
65 Brown Street
800 Albian Road
Holland House
```

I would like to order them, but ignore the numerics at the front, so they would end up in this order:

```
800 Albian Road
65 Brown Street
Holland House
1 West Road
```

Is this possible?

Comment: If you are using mariadb, `SELECT * FROM address ORDER BY REGEX_REPLACE(line1, '/^[0-9]+/', '');` might be possible. Sadly not in MySQL 5.6: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/737629/3

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [MYSQL select a piece of a string and order by that piece](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475936/mysql-select-a-piece-of-a-string-and-order-by-that-piece)

Comment: Its not quite as easy as that. Look at this [a forum](http://www.futurequest.net/forums/archive/index.php/t-20869.html) it's not like they banged out an answer

Comment: I suggest an ugly hack for now with an `alter table`, add column, and have the data in it beginning non-numeric like `PO Box 1919` or `Brown Street` and go from there. You could use a mysql function during a trigger (before or after trigger) for inserts or updates to get the cleansed non-numeric beginning part. Or maybe you could embed that function use, actually, in your query and not need that column. So I would swing for the `Function` creation

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the following function. It is tested at the bottom.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS noNumAtFront;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION noNumAtFront(s VARCHAR(100))
    RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
BEGIN
    DECLARE i,iSize INT;
    DECLARE bContinue BOOL DEFAULT TRUE;
    DECLARE ls VARCHAR(100); -- local s
    DECLARE retString VARCHAR(100);
    SET ls=LTRIM(s);
    SET iSize=LENGTH(ls);
    SET i=1;
    WHILE (i<=iSize AND bContinue) DO
        IF ASCII(SUBSTRING(ls,i,1)) NOT BETWEEN 48 AND 57 THEN
            SET bContinue=FALSE;
        ELSE
            SET i=i+1;
        END IF;
    END WHILE;
    SET retString=RIGHT(ls,iSize-i+1);
    -- RETURN CONCAT('i= ',i);
    RETURN(TRIM(retString));
END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

test

```
SELECT noNumAtFront('canal ave.');
SELECT noNumAtFront('8 fff');
SELECT noNumAtFront(' PO Box 1');
SELECT noNumAtFront('');
SELECT noNumAtFront('15151515');
SELECT noNumAtFront('5');
```

Better test:

```
CREATE TABLE addr
(   ID int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    address1 VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
INSERT addr (address1) VALUES ('canal ave.'),('123 Main St'),('3 abc lane');

select addr1 as address 
FROM 
(   select noNumAtFront(address1) as addr1 FROM addr 
) d 
ORDER BY address; 
+------------+
| address    |
+------------+
| abc lane   |
| canal ave. |
| Main St    |
+------------+
```

`d` is a derived table name. Every derived table needs a name or it errors out. A wrapper like that is needed to cleanse the function output into a name and then later (in the outer query) to sort on it.

This version 2 edit has a TRIM at the end of the function given.